# How to render all action in blender

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, actions

I have 01_a.blend. Inside 01_a.blend, I have 10 action (01_a_001. 01_a_002 ....).

I want to render all action by command line. Can anyone help me this problem?

Comment: Now I have already resolve my problem.

```
    import bpy
    obj = bpy.context.object

    for action in bpy.data.actions:
 obj.animation_data.action = bpy.data.actions.get(action.name)
 print(obj.animation_data.action)

 bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = action.name+'_'
 bpy.ops.render.render(use_viewport = True, write_still=True, animation=True)
```

run line by line in your blender file, console.
Please note that I tried run it as a script and render by command line, but it not work.